# В зависимости от выбранного RadioButton делать видимым groupBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть два groupBox'а - авторизация через новый аккаунт и через сохранённый. В зависимости от выбранного radioButton открывается либо groupBox с авторизацией нового аккаунта, либо с авторизацией сохранённого аккаунта.

Пытался сделать на событиях через groupBox.Visible = true/false, в итоге они пропадали из формы.

Как эффективней сделать?

Comment: Если надо чтобы groupBoxы не пропадали с формы, используй groupBox.Enabled= true/false

Comment: Таким образом одна налегает на другую, причём верхняя становится неактивной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой окончательный ответ. Второй radiobutton используется только для смены первого, но если Вам нужно именно два - то мой вариант Вам и подойдёт:
Здесь groupbox1 это тот который открыт при запуске формы.

```
bool checkb1 = false; //Так как с запуском ни одна не должна быть активна
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkb1 = !checkb1;
    groupBox1.Visible = checkb1;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radioButton1.Checked = true;
    groupBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

При запуске:
[image: При запуске:]

Смена:
[image: Смена]

Comment: Ну что там? Заработало?

Comment: НУ и хорошо)) Удачи